# What does pthread_exit do so that main should call it to prevent other threads from dying prematurely

Tags: c, pthreads

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_exit.3.html

The man page above does not tell why main() should terminate by calling pthread_exit, it only says that it should. Any comments will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The thread that executes `main` is special, returning from it is equivalent to call `exit` for the whole process. So this would kill all other threads.

If you just terminate it with `pthread_exit` the process keeps running until all other threads terminate one way or another.

The other alternative to give the other threads time to do their job would be to join all threads that are created by means of `pthread_join`.

Answer (score 0):

The function `pthread_exit()` allows other threads to continue execution, where as `exit(3)` will terminate every thread.